# Is it possible to extend the Instruments profiler on Mac OS X for a new language?

Tags: macos, haskell, profiling, instruments

I'd like to use the Instruments profiler on the Mac to profile Haskell code.  However, Haskell isn't a supported language by Xcode/Instruments.

Is it possible to extend Instruments to support profiling in a new/unsupported language?  What would be involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instruments is [a front-end to DTrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CreatingCustomInstruments/CreatingCustomInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH8-SW1). You can [use DTrace hooks with GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DTrace).

Comment: Thanks, these resources are helpful, and the sort of thing I'm looking for.